# how to add data to an array in while loop java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, networking

How to add str,str1,str2,str22,name,randNo to an String array,the data in loop(while) may changes each time.
when connection established,user sends data to the following program, it need to store it in an array.

```
   String s[][]=new s[100][100];
   ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(9999);
   while(true)
   {

    Socket s=ss.accept();
    DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    int str=dis.readInt();
    System.out.println("message= "+str);
    int str1=dis.readInt();
    System.out.println("message= "+str1);
    int str2=dis.readInt();
    System.out.println("message= "+str2);
    int str22=dis.readInt();
    System.out.println("message= "+str22);
    String name=dis.readUTF();
    System.out.println("message= "+name);
    int randNo=dis.readInt();
    System.out.println("Unique no:"+randNo);
    s[][]={{str,str1,str2,str22,name,randNo}};
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some index values i, j to specify the index of the String array.The data will be appended each time when the client connection established.If you want some dynamic ,auto incremented data structure , then go for ArrayList(java.utils).